# I am using ES6 syntax for node.js and I have exported module but trying to import gives error Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

index.js

```
import { Time} from './service/passport';
```

passport.js

```
const Time = async () => {
   console.log('done');
}

export { Time }
```

I am using EcmaScript or es6 in node.js but when I try to export above module it is giving me error Can't find module but I have exported module don't know why still getting error any help will be appreciated

Comment: How are you using the ES6/ESM import syntax in `index.js` yet using `require` in `passport.js`? This doesn't seem right?

Comment: It was written using require only but now I am changing syntax to ES6 but if I am trying to make normal function then also it is showing same error

Comment: Then list the error(s) in your question. As far as I know, ESM modules can't use `require` and non-ESM modules can't use the `import _ from _` syntax, which is why I'm so confused you have two files in different styles but with the same extension.

Comment: Please Check I have edited

Comment: you probably need the file extension as well: `'./service/passpost.js'`

Comment: With such a simple reproducible setup, the only thing I can think of is that your folder structure or file names are not what you expect. E.g. you should have `/index.js` and `/service/passport.js`, while your question only mentions `/passport.js`.

Comment: Only issue is to add file extension like passport.js

Comment: If you want to use ES6 modules you need to save your files as `.mjs` instead of `.js` OR you need to declare that this project is an ES6 module (instead of Commonjs module) project in your package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add file extension only instead of

```
import { Time} from './service/passport';
```

use

```
import { Time} from './service/passport.js';
```

it will be done